# Odd warning and missing _Accessor when compiling on new computer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest, accessor

I had to resurface my development computer recently, including reinstalling VS2010.  So far as I can tell, I reinstalled everything the same as previously.  However, when I compile my project I get a bunch of errors of the form:

C:\Work\CaseTrakker_v5\CaseTrakker_v5_5\Tests\CaseTrakkerCore.ComponentModel.Test\ComponentModel\NotifyPropertyChangeBaseTest.cs(100,63): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NotifyPropertyChangeBaseRef_Accessor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Also (and possibly related) I get this warning for most projects in my solution:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(287,9): warning CS1691: '2008' is not a valid warning number

I have another development machine with the same version of Visual Studio, and the same source code (fetched from version control), and everything compiles without incident.

Clearly, I have done something wrong with the installation, but I've exhausted everything I can think of.  I'd really rather not have to go back and reinstall everything from scratch (again).

Any ideas?

David Mullin

Answer (score 0):

This [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/vstscode/thread/1b6608a5-79c4-4ccc-b8e4-edc755d53935) is blaming StyleCop (R#) for this behavior. Is problably entered some information in your projects or solutions that cannot be resolved anymore. Did you have installed StyleCop or Resharper? And is it installed currently after resurfacing?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that post myself.  I have not installed any of the mentioned tools, nor did I have them before.  Honestly, the warning is the least of my concerns - the compiler error is really the problem.  It's like, all of a sudden, Visual Studio stopped creating the Accessor classes.  I know that the VS tool that does this has been deprecated, but I don't see any reason why it would work on one machine, but not on another.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that there was one important step that I omitted when resurfacing my machine - I didn't install VS 2010 SP1.  I did this, and both issues went away.

Thanks for the attention.

David Mullin